# How can I code a simple_form_for block with nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I've struggled with the Rails path, so this is what I have right now. For some reason, it works fine for the edit action, but not for the new action.

Route

```
  resources :distributors do
    resources :user_distributors, as: :users
    resources :distributor_brands, as: :brands
  end
```

Form declaration:

```
= simple_form_for @user_distributor, url: distributor_user_path(@distributor, @user_distributor), wrapper: :vertical_input_group do |f|
```

This link brings up the form for the edit action:

```
edit_distributor_user_path(@distributor, user_distributor))
```

However, this link for the does NOT bring up the correct route for the new action:

```
 new_distributor_user_path(@distributor)
```

Instead, the form declaration fails with this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user_distributors",
```

It's because the `@user_distributor`variable has no id value, so that's why it's trying to route to the show action.

How can I code that declaration so that the form works for both `new` and `edit` actions?

I have temporarily worked around this by setting the url in the actions, and that does work, but it feels like I'm missing an automatic feature here.

Comment: `= simple_form_for [@distributor, @user_distributor], wrapper: :vertical_input_group do |f|` should be able to infer the correct path without the need to pass the `url`

Comment: That's what I started out with. But it gives me this error: undefined method `distributor_user_distributor_path'.  Probably because I tried to pretty-up the route names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when you try to rename your routes as I did above. When I went back to the ugly route names, everything worked as it was supposed to with the default format:

```
= simple_form_for [@distributor, @user_distributor]
```